# htaccess url rewrite with multiple variables in url

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to make some url rewrite rules on my .htaccess file so that this link: `http://myseite.com/index.php?var1=value1&var2=value2`  will become : `http://myseite.com/var1/value2.html`

So far I have managed successfully to solve this problem but only for one variable.

I also tried this code:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
```

But it doesn't work..

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Request for 
http://mysite.com/var1/value2.html 
is rewritten to 
http://mysite.com/index.php?var1=var1&var2=var2

where index.php and .htaccess file are at the documentroot

.htaccess files will only work if httpd.conf (or some apache conf file) has "AllowOverride All"  set for the DocumentRoot you are working in. Check that first.

Next, make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache conf files (restart webserver after changing conf files) and then enable it in your .htaccess file

contents of .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# /var1/value2.html to /index.php?var1=value1&var2=value2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.html$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2
</IfModule>
```

put this in /index.php to see it work:

```
<? print_r($_GET); ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(, I have tried the ugly links and only those work.. if I try value1/value2.html it doesn't work.. It says page not found

Comment: I did run this on a real server before posting it, so it worked for me.