# Rewritten URL without id, or rewrite title by passed id

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My actual url looks like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/example.php?id=value1&name=value2
```

Ideal for me would be something like:

```
http://mydomain.com/example/value2
```

I dont want to show the items id. I googled for hours but didn`t find anything usefull.
I want to pass the id along but dont want to show it in URL. Is something like this possible?
Could i maybe rewrite the url somehow after client loaded the page?

If i must send the id then how could i rewrite the name value, accodring to id?
So if i type something not related to item with specified id in the name field, on response i sitll get the actual value for name associated to id.
So this is what i mean:

- the actual ulr is: `http://mydomain.com/example/123`
- what i type: `http://mydomain.com/randomtext/123`
- and i still get the response: `http://mydomain.com/example/123`

Just like here: http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1939/03/what-makes-an-american/309021/
If you change `what-makes-an-american` to any random text, you still get to the same page.
Do they use redirect? Isn`t that harmfull to loadtime?

Answer (score 1):

No, its not to harmful for loadtime

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# /var1/value2.html to /example.php?id=value1&name=value2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.html$ /example.php?id=$1&name=$2
</IfModule>
```

The answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930378/htaccess-url-rewrite-with-multiple-variables-in-url).

Answer (score 0):

Save this as your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

Then, you can use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable to retrieve the URL components.

For instance, with `http://mydomain.com/example/value2`:

```
$var = split('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$var becomes array('example', 'value2');
```

Comment: I dont think thats what i need. Currently I`m using this `RewriteRule ^destination/([0-9]+)/([-a-z]*)$ details.php?name=$2&id=$1 [L]` , but if i write some random thext for $2 ( name value ) it still goes to page with passed is but with wrong text. I want at least to rewrite the name part of the url to the correct one. I hope you undestand.